# osx initial login screen shows only questionmarks

Tags: macos, authentication, fonts, macos-high-sierra

I did a upgrade from macOS *el capitano* to *high sierra*. After the upgrade, the inital login screen, where you enter your password, shows the icons of my profiles and then questionmarks instead of letters.

I can login and from that point everything is normal. If I lock the screen, the login screen is normal again, as usual.

What I did already to get rid of the error:

```
ontrestore default
```

and

```
sudo atsutil databases -remove
```

recommended form [login screen characters all question marks login info isnt working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338176/login-screen-characters-all-question-marks-login-info-isnt-working).

Furhtermore I validated all fonts with via `font book` as noted here [Suddenly my MacBook Pro (Running Sierra) has question marks ...](https://qr.ae/TUnuJI)

Nothing solved the problem.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem seemd to be a permission issue. By solving [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55365955/1933185), I fixed  thereby my login screen problem.

Checking `/var/log/system.log` I discovered the following line:

```
Aug 11 09:50:33 My-MBP softwareupdated[516]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper: 666: mkdir: path=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000s0000068/C/softwareupdated/ modes[2]=0700: Permission denied
```

I did a `chmod -R 777 /var/folders/zz` and now it works. The questionmarks are gone and the login screen looks nice again.