# MacOS softwareupdated[26959]: Couldn't retrieve private cache directory path: 5

Tags: macos, installation, app-store, updates

My MacOS **App Store** does not work correctly. It is not possible to install updates or install apps from the store.

I suspect it has something todo with the following error message, which is repeated several times in /var/log/install.log.

```
2019-03-26 21:26:08+01 My-MBP softwareupdated[27061]: softwareupdated: Starting with build 10.13.6 (17G65)
2019-03-26 21:26:08+01 My-MBP softwareupdated[27061]: Couldn't retrieve private cache directory path: 5.
```

An indication is as well in my eyes, that the cli `softwareupdate` also does not work. Same for `mas` (https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/mas#default).

All programms: App Store, softwareupdate, mas behave basically in the same way. After the start nothings happens. 
E.g:

#### App store

starts up. When I click on the icon *updates* the "rainbow spinner" appears and the app freezes. Same when I try to install an App. I can close the App Store only if I do a `killall "App Store"`

#### mas

```
mas install 425424353
==> Downloading The Unarchiver
# Nothing happens
```

#### softwareupdate:

```
softwareupdate -l
Software Update Tool
Finding available software
# Nothing happens
```

**Does someone have a hint, how I could fix this problem with the missing private cache directory?**

Some information:

- OSX 10.13.6 (on a macbook early 2011)
- App Store 2.4 (658.1)
- softwareupdated: Starting with build 10.13.6 (17G65)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking `/var/log/system.log` I discovered the following line:

```
Aug 11 09:50:33 My-MBP softwareupdated[516]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper: 666: mkdir: path=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000s0000068/C/softwareupdated/ modes[2]=0700: Permission denied
```

I did a `chmod -R 777 /var/folders/zz` and now it works. I could update my system. Furthermore the `chmod ...` fixed [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54163487/1933185) I had with my mac.